# How to send input to tar through pipe with a variable having list of files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have searched about this in internet, but all are saying to use -T option or find /DIR | tar -c.

But i am having list of files in a variable and i have to give input via pipe to tar.
example,

`grep -v "*" ${filelist} | tar -cf gk.tar`

I dint want to create intermediate file and get output from that file.

Comment: What is in filelist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer , as using '-T -' will get input from pipe.

example,

```
 grep -v "*" ${cpiolist} |tar -T - -cf gk.tar
```

Comment: If you have a file containing the list, you should be able to simply write `tar -T cpiolist97 -cf gk.tar`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grep -v "*" ${filelist} | xargs tar -cf gk.tar
```

Checkout the xargs manual. It may not work if the file list is too long.